# I want a class A to use a method of class B, and I want a method of class A be used by class B

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

I'm doing a little project for school where I try to do a spreadsheet program, and I have two classes, I will be simplifying this with pseudocode a little bit so it's not too messy.

```
class DocumentController {
    Document doc // This is a class with a CRUD on a document (It haves 
        // Sheets and every Sheet haves a Table full of Cells)
    Parser p

    getValueOfCell (sheetName, positionX, positionY) {
         returns value of a cell in a sheet in the position x,y
    }
    
    setCell (String expression, sheetName, positionX, positionY) {
         //Somewhere here we need to use p.evaluate()
    }
 
}

class Parser {
    DocumentController docController;
    evaluate (expression: String) {
        //Somewhere here, I need to use method getCell from Document 
        // for evaluating the  expression (The expressions have 
        // references to other cells so the Parser need to resolve 
        // these references)
        ...
        return value of the expression (float, integer, string, whatever)
    }
}
```

So apparently my teacher said to me that this is a bad design, because these classes are too coupled and this is a code smell. Can someone explain me why is this so bad? How can I make a better design?

Thank you, sorry if I made some typos or the code is not legible

Comment: Have a look at the reference links here: [Spot problems with circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37445480/1371329).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
Class Main{
   public void main(){
     DocumentController dc = new DocumentController();
     //you can get ahold of the parser by
     Parser p = dc.getParser();
   }
}



Class Parser{
      DocumentController dc;
      public Parser(DocumentController dc){
         this.dc = dc;
      }
     //your methods
   }



Class DocumentController{
   Parser p;

public DocumentController(){
     this.p = new Parser(this);
   }
   
   public Parser getParser(){
      return this.p;
   }
   //your methods

  }
```

Although there are probably better ways of doing this instead like passing your object to the method when you need it. Something like

```
 Class Main{
    public void main(){
     DocumentController dc = new DocumentController();
     Parser p = new Parser();
     p.myParserMethod(dc);
     dc.myDocMethod(p);
    }
 }


 Class Parser{
    public myParserMethod(DocumentController dc){
        //you can use the same documentController object here
    }
}

Class DocumentController{
   public myDocMethod(Parser p){ 
    //you can use your parser object here
   }

}
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to format value by some key expression. If yes, then we can create mapping between this key expression and format classes. Then we can use `Factory` pattern to create desired objects to format your cell value.

Let me show a simple example via C#.

So this is a DocumentController:

```
public class DocumentController
{
    private DocumentService _documentService;

    public DocumentController()
    {
        _documentService = new DocumentService(); // this dependency can be 
            // resolved by IoC container
    }

    public void GetValueCell(int docId, string sheetName, int positionX, 
        int positionY)
    {
        _documentService.GetValueCell(docId, sheetName, positionX, 
            positionY);
    }

    public void SetCell(int docId, string expression, string sheetName, int 
        positionX, int positionY, object value)
    { 
        _documentService.SetCell(docId, expression, sheetName, positionX, 
            positionY, value);
    }
}
```

And this is a service which will execute logic related to `Document`:

```
public class DocumentService
{
    private DocumentRepository _documentRepository;

    public DocumentService()
    {
        _documentRepository = new DocumentRepository();
    }

    public string GetValueCell(int docId, string sheetName, int positionX, int positionY)
    {
        Document document = _documentRepository.GetById(docId);
        return document.GetCellValue(sheetName, positionX, positionY);
    }

    public void SetCell(int docId, string expression, string sheetName, int 
        positionX, int positionY, object value)
    {
        Document document = _documentRepository.GetById(docId);
        document.SetCellValue(expression, sheetName, positionX, positionY, 
            value);
    }

}
```

It is unknown how you get `Document`, but it is possible to use repository pattern for that purpose.

```
public class DocumentRepository 
{
    public Document GetById(int id) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

and this is a `Document` class:

```
public class Document 
{
    private object[][] _cells;

    public Document(int x)
    {
        _cells = new object[x][];
    }

    public string GetCellValue(string sheetName, int positionX, int positionY) 
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public void SetCellValue(string expression, string sheetName, int 
        positionX, int positionY, object value)
    {
        FormatterType formatterType = new 
            FormatterTypeToExpression().FormatterByExpression[expression];
        Formatter formatter = new FormatterFactory().
            FormatterByFormatterType[formatterType];
        object formattedCell = formatter.Format(value);
        _cells[positionX][positionY] = formattedCell;
    }
}
```

and this is a mapping between FormatterType and your key expression:

```
public class FormatterTypeToExpression
{
    public Dictionary<string, FormatterType> FormatterByExpression { get; set; } = 
        new Dictionary<string, FormatterType>
    {
        { "string", FormatterType.String}
        // here you write expressions and foramtters
    };
}
```

This is a formatter type:

```
public enum FormatterType
{
    String, Number, Decimal, Whatever
}
```

Then you need something like factory to take a formatter:

```
public abstract class Formatter 
{
    public abstract object Format(object value);
}
```

And abstract class which will define behavior of derived formatter classes:

```
public class FormatterString : Formatter
{
    public override object Format(object value)
    {
        return "I am a formatted string value";
    }
}
```

An example how `FormatterFactory` could look like:

```
public class FormatterFactory
{
    public Dictionary<FormatterType, Formatter> FormatterByFormatterType { get; set; }  
        = new Dictionary<FormatterType, Formatter>
    {
        { FormatterType.String, new FormatterString()}
        // here you write FormatterType and formatters
    };
}
```